# Why dropdown list goes under the sticky element?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-lists, dropdown

I have a table in which last two columns are fixed by position = sticky because I needed to remove them from scrolling. I need to put a dropdown list in one fixed column. But my dropdown list is going under the sticky element why this is happening? I tried to set z-index to dropdown list but it is not working
can anyone tell me what is I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the parent element of a dropdown will be position:relative and the content of the dropdown will have Position:absolute. So Position:sticky on a dropdown might not work.

Edit: 
You cannot make a dropdown by using position:sticky; . But to solve your problem there is a way where you can stick your last two columns using position:absolute; and add a dropdown. Here's a jsfiddle that can help you
[Click](https://jsfiddle.net/Akash951/q2sctfwz/) `<a>https://jsfiddle.net/Akash951/q2sctfwz/</a>` **Note:** when you add a dropdown here make sure you use z-index more than the column so that the dropdown content comes on top.

Comment: how can i provide a code snippet? I don't know how to make a running code snippet in stack overfow

Comment: You can use jsfiddle or codepen where you can place your code with problem and share the link.

Comment: In place of the name add <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>. For the dropdown-content class give the style z-index:1001;

Comment: I need to fix column using sticky and i need a dropdown inside that. can I have both

Comment: As I mentioned using the column as sticky you cannot add a drop-down. But you can get the same behaviour by adding position:absolute in the column. And add a drop-down with a greater z-index